# JavaScript - cannot import js file to test in meteor

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, meteor

I want to write some simple application test (Meteor JS). It was not a problem to import modules from packages to the test file, but when I am trying to import the app.js file, the app:

1) crashes, when the app.tests.js file is in the main app folder and I am trying to import the /client/app.js file

2) When i have my testing file in './client' folder (in the place where is app.js file), after importing the .js none of the tests are loading (the site is blank, even though i have 7 tests returning true).

The helpers I have are in one app.js file in the client folder. Below is one of the helpers I have:

```
    if (Meteor.isClient) { 
      Template.app.helpers({
        readyForAction: () => Session.get("ready")
      })
    }
```